# recognize mouse click over a flash element

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, mouseclick-event

This is a really though one.

I have wrtitten this javascript to connect actions in javascripts and actions in a flash application in my [site](http://s-maof.com/Forum). 
The flash app is a bar that displays reltime indices. 
But it has **4 rows** . The user can choose which row to display by pressing 
the up or down arrow.
I am trying to recognize if the user click one of those buttons by recognizing the x and y with

```
e.pageX and e.pageY
```

This should works (and it does!) becuase the flash is always on the bottom (fixed position)
The thing is that it works in FF but not in chrome or IE.

The code is

```
$('body').click(function(e){

    var arrowWidth  = 15;
    var arrowHeight = 12;

    x_left      = $("body").width() * 0.88 - 30;
    x_right     = $("body").width() * 0.88;

    y_down_bottom       = $(window).height() -2//screen.height; //$
    y_down_top      = y_down_bottom - arrowHeight;
    y_up_bottom     = y_down_bottom - arrowHeight-2;
    y_up_top        = y_up_bottom   - arrowHeight-4;


    if (e.pageX > x_left && e.pageX < x_right ){
        if (e.pageY>=y_down_top && e.pageY<=y_down_bottom ){
                    //pressed down
                      .............
                   }
        }
```

EDIT:

Comment: It's better to make the Flash movie itself communicate with the page, can you do it? I mean can you modify and recompile the Flash movie?

Comment: 1. Can you give example code for that.

Comment: 2. I'm not erally a flash coder but If the code is simple enough, mayble I acn manage

Comment: Have a look here: [http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html]

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work in IE (I've edited the question). any Idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to carnio I changed my approach by sending it through flash external interface.
I used

```
import flash.external.*; // for sending up and down arrows events to javascript
```

and this on the press up and down events

```
//update javascript
// The name of a JavaScript function to call 
var callJasFunction:String = "GetBtnTicker";
//parameter 
var msg:int = page;
//  The return value after calling JavaScript 
ExternalInterface.call(callJasFunction, msg);
```

and it works.

Comment: It's nice to see someone who actually bothered to work it out on their own - good work.